# Load images one by one in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having a uniquecode text in my recyclerview list item and by using that i have to call an API and get image URL and load it in the appropriate list item.

I am using **retrofit** for getting the image url form API.

I am calling the retrofit on **onBindViewHolder** of adapter in recyclerview.

In my android log i can see the response of retrofit and for the first 6 list item of recyclerview i am getting correct image and for the next list items the same 6 images are repeating. Anyone got this type of issue.

Please help me to overcome this.

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide onBindViewHolder code of retrofit call ?

Comment: The uniquecode text in your maintaining for your recyclerview items is different all items.. Can you confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation, You are making Two Network Call in onBindViewHolder, one for getting the image URL using the uniquecode text and another one for Loading The Url, the first one is not very useful unless the image url change while you scroll the RecyclerView(i guess not),

Another approach would be to first, fetch the image Url and put that Url in your item(list) for the RecyclerView and then only load the image Url in your RecyclerView Adapter

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch your picture links outside ViewHolder in to a list, and use pagination or something similar for downloading more items when scrolled.